# Creating Text File with Variable as the File Name

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, filenames

I'm trying to create a new text file with a variable assigned as the name of the file; to add todays date to each file created. Though continue to receive the same error-

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TestFileWrite_10/11/2020.txt'
```

I've tried these methods with no success-

**Using str-**

```
today = date.today()
filename = "TestFileWrite_" + today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
f = open(str(filename)+'.txt', "w")
f.write(output1)
# output1 var is referenced within another part of the script.
f.close()
```

**Using %-**

```
today = date.today()
filename = "TestFileWrite_" + today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
f = open("%s.txt" % filename, "w")
f.write(output1)
# output1 var is referenced within another part of the script.
f.close()
```

**Using .format-**

```
today = date.today()
filename = "TestFileWrite" + str(today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
f = open("{}.txt".format(filename), "w")
f.write(output1)
# output1 var is referenced within another part of the script.
f.close()
```

Comment: You seem to have `/` in your filenames. These will be re-interpreted as folder-name delimiters. Did you mean `"TestFileWrite_10-11-2020.txt"`?

Comment: Completely overlooked the date creation, fixed my issue, thank you @quamrana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove or replace the slash bar in:

```
filename = "TestFileWrite_" + today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

The date format should be changed, for example:

```
filename = "TestFileWrite_" + today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

or

```
filename = "TestFileWrite_" + today.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
```

Moreover, the type of 'filename' is already 'str', so there is no need to use str() function:

```
f = open(filename+'.txt', 'w')
```